# How do I calculate billing cycle from given date in PHP?

Tags: php, date, billing

I want to get result as below.

Datum point of Billing Day : 21

Regular billing period is 2015-01-21 to 2015-02-20, 2015-02-21 to 2015-03-20, 2015-03-21 to 2015-04-20, ... ... ...

**For the First month  to make a billing period.**

When customer register start date (2015-01-13) and end date (2015-05-10) before than 2015-01-21 (billing day 21),
I want to make a period as 2015-01-13 to 2015-01-20.

but if customer register start date (2015-01-25) and end date (2015-05-25) after than 2015-01-21, I want to make a period as 2015-01-25 to 2015-02-20.

**For the Last month**

When customer **end registration** is 2015-05-10 before billing day (2015-05-21), I want to make a period as 2015-04-21 to 2015-05-10.

When customer **end registration** is 2015-05-25 after billing day (2015-05-21) , I want to make a period as 2015-05-21 to 2015-05-25.

ex1) Given start date : 2015-01-10, Given end date : 2015-03-19

Result:

```
$array[0]['start'] = 2015-01-10;
$array[0]['end'] = 2015-01-20;
$array[1]['start'] = 2015-01-21;
$array[1]['end'] = 2015-02-20;
$array[2]['start'] = 2015-02-21;
$array[2]['end'] = 2015-03-19;
```

ex2) Given start date : 2015-01-24, Given end date : 2015-03-25

Billing day: 21

Result:

```
$array[0]['start'] = 2015-01-24;
$array[0]['end'] = 2015-02-20;
$array[1]['start'] = 2015-02-21;
$array[1]['end'] = 2015-03-20;
$array[2]['start'] = 2015-03-21;
$array[2]['end'] = 2015-03-25;
```

ex3) Given start date : 2015-01-24, Given end date : 2015-04-18

Billing Day : 21

Result:

```
$array[0]['start'] = 2015-01-24;
$array[0]['end'] = 2015-02-20;
$array[1]['start'] = 2015-02-21;
$array[1]['end'] = 2015-03-20;
$array[2]['start'] = 2015-03-21;
$array[2]['end'] = 2015-04-18;
```

I made a function as below but this function has a last month problem.

```
function dateRange($firstDate, $lastDate, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d', $period='21' ){
        $dates = array();

        $first  = strtotime($firstDate); 
        $current= strtotime($firstDate);
        $last   = strtotime($lastDate);

        $startSet = $period;
        $endSet = $period - 1;

        $startFormat = "Y-m-{$startSet}";
        $endFormat = "Y-m-{$endSet}";

        $startMonth = date("Y-m", $first);
        $endMonth = date("Y-m", $last);

        $i=0;

        while( $current <= $last ){    

            if($first==$current){
                // first month

                $dates[$i]['start'] = $firstDate;

                $chkStartDay = date("d", $first);
                if($chkStartDay < $period){

                    // end period of first month.
                    $dates[$i]['end'] = date($endFormat, $current);

                    // if start date is bigger than 21 period, add array
                    $i++;

                    $dates[$i]['start'] = date($startFormat, $current);
                    $dates[$i]['end'] = date($endFormat, strtotime("+1 month", $current));


                }else{
                    $dates[$i]['end'] = date($endFormat, strtotime("+1 month", $current));
                }

            }else{

                $dates[$i]['start'] = date($startFormat, $current);
                $dates[$i]['end'] = date($endFormat, strtotime("+1 month", $current));;


            }

            $current = strtotime($step, $current);

            $i++;
        }



        return $dates;
}

$dates = dateRange('2015-01-12', '2015-05-23', "+1 month", "Y-m-d", '21');//increase by one month
```

Thanks

Comment: We would love to help answer your question, but there seems to be a lot of information missing. Where do these dates come from? Is there a datasource for all these dates? Why are you doing it in PHP? It seems like this type of data massaging could be done with a simple script.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I modified the question, please check it again.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime` for this

like this:

```
$startDateString = '2015-01-10';
$startDate = new DateTime($startDateString);
$newDate = $startDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // P1D adds one day
```

You could create a `for` loop to construct the desired array as result.
See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) on `DateInterval` for more info.

Good luck!

Comment: I am using less than PHP 5.3 so I can't use DateInterval.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1736363: in either way, use `->modify('+1 day')` on DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified my function as below and it works, if someone knows better code, please let me know.

```
function dateRange($firstDate, $lastDate, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d', $period='21' ){
        $dates = array();

        $first  = strtotime($firstDate); 
        $current= strtotime($firstDate);
        $last   = strtotime($lastDate);

        $startSet = $period;
        $endSet = $period - 1;

        $startFormat = "Y-m-{$startSet}";
        $endFormat = "Y-m-{$endSet}";


        $i=0;
        $loopEnd = true;
        while( $current <= $last ){    

            if($first==$current){
                //Start Month

                $dates[$i]['startDate'] = $firstDate;

                $chkStartDay = date("d", $first);
                if($chkStartDay < $period){


                    $dates[$i]['endDate'] = date($endFormat, $current);

                }else{
                    $dates[$i]['endDate'] = date($endFormat, strtotime("+1 month", $current));
                }

                $nextDateEnd = $dates[$i]['endDate'];

            }else{


                $dates[$i]['startDate'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($nextDateEnd)));
                $dates[$i]['endDate'] = date($endFormat, strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($dates[$i]['startDate'])));;   


                if($lastDate < $dates[$i]['endDate']){
                    $dates[$i]['endDate'] = $lastDate;
                    $loopEnd = false;
                }

            }

            $nextDateStart = $dates[$i]['startDate'];
            $nextDateEnd = $dates[$i]['endDate'];

            $current = strtotime($step, $current);

            $i++;
        }


        if($lastDate > date($endFormat, strtotime($lastDate)) and $loopEnd == true ){
            $i++;

            $dates[$i]['startDate'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($nextDateEnd)));
            $dates[$i]['endDate'] = $lastDate; 


        }

        return $dates;
}

$dates = dateRange('2015-01-11', '2015-05-27', "+1 month", "Y-m-d", '21');//increase by one month
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [start] => 2015-01-10
        [end] => 2015-01-20
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2015-01-21
        [end] => 2015-02-20
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2015-02-21
        [end] => 2015-03-20
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2015-03-21
        [end] => 2015-04-20
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2015-04-21
        [end] => 2015-05-11
    )
```

)